# Snapchat-like app

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to have a "Snapchat-like" UWP app.

Here is a small piece of code:

```
 <Grid>
            <CaptureElement Stretch="Uniform"/>
            <Button 
                    x:Name="button1" 
                    Content="Button" 
                    Height="126"  Width="162" 
                    Click="button1_Click" 
                    FontSize="72"
                    Margin="185,543,0,51"/>

</Grid>
```

However, as I want my app to be capable of being used on Phone and Desktop, I would like to be able to resize the window and let it auto-adjust (using **VisualStateManager**)

I tried using Rows to accomplish that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CaptureElement Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button 
            x:Name="button1" 
            Content="Button" 
            Height="126"  Width="162" 
            Click="button1_Click" 
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

This seemed to be ok, but the picture is not fullscreen - you can clearly separate Button from the CapturePreview,but the idea is to have fullscreen preview with just button icons.

Is there a way to accomplish what I have in mind?

Comment: Can `<CaptureElement Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>` solve the problem?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT would you add that to the first code or the second one?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT  Thanks that actually made the icon visible, but now the captureElement is stretched out.

Comment: second one of course. You can refer to [Grid.RowSpan attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowspan.aspx) to see the function of `RowSpan` .

Comment: What you mean by `stretched out`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Actually - If I use Uniform, I get black bars on the side; if I use UniformToFill I get only Left corner of my camera, but the whole CaptureElement is covered.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no margin outside the `CaptureElement`? Actually you can check the official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit), I didn't see this problem. We should avoid extended discussions in comments, if there is no problem, I write the comments here as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, that is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [Grid.RowSpanProperty property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowspanproperty.aspx) here.

Since you divide your `Grid` into two parts:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

If you want your `CaptureElement` to stretch to the whole `Grid`, you can set the `Grid.RowSpan="2"` here:

`<CaptureElement Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>`

By the way, you can refer to the official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) in case you have other questions about camera.